# Linestrings created in R is not getting plotted right

Tags: r, sf

I need to create multiple linestrings (transects) based on multiple coordinates, and then plot them (for a study area map) and later on, I will use these lines for joining attributes from another data set and in other spatial analyses.

The first part --creating the linestrings-- seems to work fine for me, based on all (great) answers in [R - Create multiple linestrings from multiple coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/312289/196155) & Guzmán's answer in [R: sf package points to multiple lines with st_cast](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/270725). If I use `mapview::mapview()`, they all return the transects. But when I try to plot it through `ggplot2` it returns me:

> Error in st_transform.sfc(X[[i]], ...) :
> cannot transform sfc object with missing crs

When I set a `crs` and try to plot it, it plots in a completelly different location than expected (pretty much out of the globe, hehe). I've tried setting the `crs` in different parts of the code, check the ## in the code below, e.g. inside the function in `st_linestring`, and outside the function in `st_sfc`, `st_sf`, or even using `st_crs(lines) <- 4326`.

Please find below the code I'm using.

```
library(tidyverse); library(rnaturalearth); library(sf); library(mapview)

df_tbl <- tibble::tribble(
  ~lat,   ~lon,   ~lat2,   ~lon2,
  -34.305, 173.520, -34.461, 173.258,
  -34.461, 173.258, -34.214, 173.378,
  -34.214, 173.378, -34.362, 173.113)

rows <- split(df_tbl, seq(nrow(df_tbl)))

lines <- lapply(rows, function(row) {
  lmat <- matrix(unlist(row[1:4]), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  st_linestring(lmat) # I've tried crs = 4326 here
})

lines <- st_sfc(lines) # I've tried crs = 4326 here

lines_sf <- st_sf('ID' = 1:3, 'geometry' = lines) # I've tried crs = 4326 here

# st_crs(lines) <- 4326 # And I also tried like this... 

mapview::mapview(lines_sf)
```

I'm trying to plot it along with the tip of New Zealand's North Island:

```
nz_sf <- 
  rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", 
                              country = "new zealand", 
                              returnclass = "sf")

## After setting a 'crs' for 'lines_sf'
p <- 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = nz_sf) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(172.5,173.8), ylim = c(-34.2,-34.9))+ # This just work if the line below is commented 
  geom_sf(data = lines_sf) +
  theme_bw()
```

Checking `attributes(lines_sf$geometry)` shows me that, apparently, it's all good with projection.

It is the first time I'm "building" spatial features inside R from scratch, and I might be doing something wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: Tip: avoid `library(tidyverse)` - it pulls in so many packages you don't need here. You only need `ggplot2` and `tribble`, and you don't really need `tribble` for making examples. The lighter you can keep your examples the easier they are for people to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your latitude and longitude swapped. If I plot and label the axes I see you have latitudes greater than 90, which is a big clue:

```
> plot(lines_sf$geom)
> axis(1)
> axis(2)
```

[image]

`st_linestring` takes coords in X,Y order, but you are passing lat,long, which is Y,X. Flip those columns and you'll be sorted.

Something like:

```
lines <- lapply(rows, function(row) {
  lmat <- matrix(unlist(row[c(2,1,4,3)]), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  st_linestring(lmat) # I've tried crs = 4326 here
})
```

should get you there.

Comment: Ouch - that was a noobie error! Many thanks, @Spacedman - it worked perfectly now. Thanks also for the comment above. I'll pay more attention to the packages needed next time :)